# How to display image on webpage from javascript object key

Tags: javascript, image, object

I just started learning JS, so this is exercise for me.

I have array of objects, for loop and input button.

```js
var auto = [
    {
        ime: 'Fica',
        prod: '1955-1985',
        info: 'The Zastava 750....',
        img: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Zastava_850_f.jpg/800px-Zastava_850_f.jpg'

    },
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById("automobili");
var myH2 = document.getElementById("ime");
var myH3 = document.getElementById("prod");
var myH4 = document.getElementById("info");
var myH5 = document.getElementById('img');

function getInfo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < auto.length; i++) {
        if(input.value == auto[i].ime) {
            myH2.innerText = auto[i].ime;
            myH3.innerText = auto[1].prod;
            myH4.innerText = auto[i].info;
            myH5.innerText = auto[i].img;
            return;
        }    
    }
```

Input and loop is working, when i enter name it displays name of a car, prod years and info, but how to display image of a specific car on a webpage?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If your myH5 is an img element, this should do the job. Not sure if you noticed that you are using 'url' and 'imgUrl' key naming conventions for your image url in your data.

```
myH5.setAttribute("src", auto[i].img || auto[i].imgUrl );
```